# Python I/O User Input

Tags: python, if-statement, input, io, notepad

The question I am trying to get answered is if you can use Python's I/O implementation to test if a file contains a certain word or phrase and then to run some more code. The goal that I would want to have with this is to have all of the interaction take place in Notepad. This would require some form of `if` statements interaction with the `read` function in I/O as far as I can see.

I would want to write code along the lines of:

```
while True: #Using a while loop to re-ask if not valid answer.
    color = input("What is your favorite color? [red/blue/green] ").lower() #Asking and converting to lowercase.
    if color == "red" or color == "blue" or color == "green": #Testing if color is valid.
        break #Escaping the loop
    else: #If it's not valid:
        print("Wow, I have never heard of " + color + " being a color before")
        continue #Restarting the loop
print("Really? " + color + " is my favorite color too!") #Because they got out of the loop, we can run this.
```

...into some form of it being in Notepad. Again, I would like the question to be asked in Notepad, the question to be answered by the user in Notepad, and then set return some text in Notepad.

Comment: My little answer is: http://xkcd.com/1425/ . _It can be hard to explain the difference between the easy and the virtually impossible._

Comment: You keep repeating "in Notepad", but it's really not clear what you mean, or why. Notepad is a text editor, it doesn't provide interactive scripting capabilities.

Comment: as a joke, you may consider writing your own NOTEPAD and your desire feature as a built-in

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you not do the read and write functions to interact with a .txt file?

Comment: You actually want to contact with the user using a .txt file or Notepad?

Comment: @qqvc, I really really like that :)

Comment: And yes, to everybody, I know this is a bad idea. I just want to know if something like this is possible.

Comment: @qqvc That's the idea anyways.

Comment: By "notepad", do you mean a terminal window?

Comment: @user1245262 I mean the program notepad for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't use Notepad for that, Notepad is a text editor, you can't use your scripts in that, but you can open Notepad with Python, its not what you want anyways. If we want to contact with user, we using *input* so we can contact with the user. So this is actually means your script is an interactive shell. This is how we contact with the user, but you want it with Notepad which means like, we have an apple and we can eat it but we want to eat it while the apple inside a lion mouth. It's not possible doing it with Notepad or .txt file, but you can make a database with .txt file or SQlite and you can check informations given by user, are that informations in your database or not.

Comment: Thank you for telling me what is and isn't possible to do with this.